# API for the mobile feed, as seen in the Android app?

Tags: support, api

I'm creating an app for Windows 10, and I would like to provide a similar experience to the official Android and iOS apps (while keeping my own identity, of course).

One feature seen in the official apps is the “Feed”, which is a combination of the inbox, hot questions from my sites, and other stuff like Careers 2.0. However, I've read the documentation from top to bottom, and I can't find an endpoint for this Feed.

So, is there any way to get the Feed from a third-party app, or is it exclusive to the official apps?

Comment: Nope.  But if you packet sniff the official app, you might be able to discover and use the same endpoint(s).  They're usually simple JSON `GET`s, sometimes websockets.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I just tried it, and it's a GET request, with an access token and key. Trying to use my keys gives me a 403 error.

Comment: Did you use your key to get an access token with max permissions?  Also, scope the official app's auth call and see if it asks for a hidden permission.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I checked it, and it gets their tokens from a different endpoint. Instead of using OAuth as explained [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), it makes a direct login to https://mobile.stackexchange.com/1/login. I haven't tested it with my own app, but it seems that this domain is for internal use.

Comment: Bummer.  You can assemble some of the info with existing API paths. Look-for/upvote feature request for the rest.  Make a feature request, if needed, on [metase] -- but public API development seems mostly stalled.